# Back end: Not able to print&send email under order 500

Tags: invoice, order-email, memory, print, magento-1.9.1.1

After installing two extensions - 
S4 Customizable PDF Invoice Template
and
Fooman Email Attachments
(OK I had Aschroders SMTP Pro also before)

This happened in back end:

I can not print or send an email in ORDER view, I get 500

BUT

I CAN print AND send an email in INVOICE view

BUT whY?!

Have tried:

1) Clearing caches, reindexing, no complilation
2) installed extension to check if there is plugin conflict, there is none

one is shown resolved
Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email_Queue
Fooman_EmailAttachments_Model_Core_Email_Queue  Resolved

3) We had some error messages and we raised PHP memory limit...not sure how much, but it seems to be not working or was not enough

How come this is happening? Can it still be about PHP memory limit?

If it is can it be that the limit is so high cause of "badly compatible" plugins?

But how come I get to print invoice?
Working on magento 1.9.1.1, all patches except the last small Zend patch added